# preg_replace every custom chars but URLs

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

hi i'm using WordPress and i want to replace the following

```
$items = array( ".","?","!",",","؟","،",":","™","*" );
```

so i made up this function

```
function Huemix_content_filter_chars($content){
$items = array();
$items = array( ".","?","!",",","؟","،",":","™","*" );
$before='<span class="kindared">';
$after='</span>';
foreach ( $items as $k => $val ) {
    $content = preg_replace("|(\\$val)|","$before$1$after",$content);
     $content = preg_replace("|(<[^>]+?)($before(\\$val)$after)([^<]+?>)|","$1$3$4",$content);
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'Huemix_content_filter_chars');
```

and i didn't understand whats wrong !
it's working, but not exactly 
it's break this link

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/huemix.ly">Huemix Studio, Inc™</a>
```

it's printed like this

```
<a href="http&lt;span class=" kindared"="">://facebook<span class="kindared">.</span>com/huemix<span class="kindared">.</span>ly"&gt;Huemix Studio<span class="kindared">,</span> Inc<span class="kindared">™</span></a>
```

but it doesn't breaking the second link

```
    Follow Us On Facebook <a href="http://facebook.com/huemix.ly">Huemix Studio, Inc™</a>

Follow Us On Twitter <a href="http://twitter.com/HuemixStudio">Huemix Studio, Inc™</a>
```

you can see my problem online here

and it's braking my posts images and here is the output for my html posts images

```
<div class="huemix-works "><img class='huemix-works-image' alt='Huemix Studio Works' src='http://alpha.huemix.ly/wp-content/uploads/Huemix_temp/NASER-GROUP1-698998_140x94.png' /><span class='huemix-works-overlay'></span><a class="huemix-works-zoom-icon huemix-fancybox" title="Huemix Studio Works" href="http://alpha.huemix.ly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/NASER-GROUP1.png" rel="media">Zoom In</a></div>
```

Please take a look at my problem online [here](http://alpha.huemix.ly/contact-us/) and [here](http://alpha.huemix.ly/golden-anchor/) , it's my demo site 
Please see it it's breaking somethings but another things works fine !
help please !

Comment: This looks like a case of "you need to reduce the code". Write a test case, pump it with input, see output that is erroneous, reduce code as much as possible while repeating the problem. Basic debugging.

Though it looks you're trying to be too smart with regexp, and don't understand how regexp works →  its producing garbage as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use str_replace?

```
$items = array( ".","?","!",",","؟","،",":","™","*" );
$content = str_replace($items, '', $content);
```

Comment: my problem not in the method !
it's in not replacing any link in my website